# Setting page margins in Rave Reports

Tags: delphi, printing, margins, rave-reports

I am using Rave Report to print my reports in Delphi. Is there a way i can set the page margins(left, right, top and bottom) for printing my reports? please help me....

Answer (score 0):

May be this is useful for you (It's detailed document so I write the link)

**[How do I create or modify reports that use the Rave engine without using the visual designer.](http://www.nevrona.com/Products/RaveReports/TipsTricks/TipsRaveGeneral/Tip079CreateReportswithoutVisualDesigner/tabid/144/Default.aspx)**